# Oracle Apex - Refresh Region using dynamic action

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to refresh dynamically a region on a page from dynamic action. I have a select list loaded from the database.When the select list change its value, the region will refresh.
the the source of my region contains a img tag like this:

```
<img src="#APP_IMAGES#&P10_language..png" />
```

The problem here is when i change the select list,
the image still unchanged and it doesn't refresh.

Is there a solution ?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://spendolini.blogspot.com/2015/11/refreshing-plsql-regions-in-apex.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to change select list item's **Page action on selection**. Currently, it is "None" (I presume). If you set it to e.g. **Redirect and set value**, browser will redirect to current page (and refresh it), while select list item's value will be *stored* into the session state.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to refresh the entire page, you can

- create a dynamic action on change of the item that refreshes the region
- ensure your region is some form of refreshable region (classic/IR/IG)
- ensure you set the item in the 'page items to submit' region property

And ideally not use &ITEM. syntax in your SQL